# average cell with text and number based on the value of the text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The cells of my row contain both text and numbers. It is always one letter and two digits.

Example - B30, B35, F30, B40, F32, F34, B33...

I'd like to average the cells that start with "B" separate from the cells that start with "F".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this "array formula" assuming data in `A2:Z2`

`=AVERAGE(IF(LEFT(A2:Z2)="B",MID(A2:Z2,2,2)+0))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: This works. I was sniffing around it and had trouble getting the Left = "B" part to work. Thanks.

For my understanding, why add the + 0 after defining the two numbers with MID?

Comment: The result of MID function is always a text value (same applies to other functions like LEFT and RIGHT) so you need to convert that text to a number or `AVERAGE` function will ignore it, using +0 is one way to do that (you could also use *1 or any other method that performs a calculation while leaving the value unchanged)

Comment: I'm looking to take this formula and step it up further by creating a weighted average. Is there a way to take this same concept but create a weighted average based on how many of the values have B and how many have F? Say 8 of 12 start with B, and 4 start with F.

Comment: Can you give some sample data and the expected results?

Comment: a row has: F31, F28, B32, F29, F31, F28, F29, F32, B33, F28

My formula is 'code' =IF(COUNTIF(E8:T8,"F*")>=4,AVERAGE(SMALL(IF(LEFT(E8:T8)="F",MID(E8:T8,2,2)+0),{1,2,3,4})),AVERAGE(IF(LEFT(E8:T8)="F",MID(E8:T8,2,2)+0)))

The average of F is 28.3. The same formula looking at B comes to 32.5.

I'd like to weight the average knowing that 8 of 10 come from "F" values and 2 of 10 come from "B" values. 8 of 10 and 2 of 10 is not always going to be the ratio of F and B values.

Comment: Well you could multiply the count by the average for each letter then average the result, so that would be =(28.3*8+32.5*2)/10......except that takes into account all 8 "F" values but you are only averaging the lowest 4 so you might want that to be =(28.3*`4`+32.5*2)/`6`

Answer (score 0):

what I'd do is use an if to separate the b's from the f's into 2 rows and then average both rows. so in an empty row you'd do:

`=if(Left(A1,1) = "B", A1, "")` and then drag that down for the entire row. that will separate out all the "b"'s, and you can average the row. then do `=if(Left(A1,1) = "F", A1, "")` on a different row, and drag the formula accross, and average the rows

HTH